# Basic surface integral with Stokes.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Calculate surface integral $\iint_S \nabla \times \mathbf{F} \bullet \mathbf{n} \; dS$ with stokes, when
$$\mathbf{F}=\left\langle\frac{5y(z-1)}{6},xz, 6e^{xy}\cos{z}\right\rangle$$
and $S$ is surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, $z \geq0$, which's positive side is the above side.

My work so far..
$$S=\{r\in[0,2], \phi \in [0,2\pi]\}$$
$$\begin{align} \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 ((\frac{\overbrace{z}^{=0}+5}{6})\mathbf{k}\bullet \mathbf{k}) r \; d rd \phi &= \frac 56 \times \text{area of circle with radius of 2} \\ &=\frac 56\times4\pi = \frac {10}{3} \pi \end{align}$$

Comment: For the line integral you need the boundary curve $C$ of $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The flux of $\text{curl}\,\mathbf F$ is the same across *any* oriented surface with the same boundary curve.

Comment: How can I find the boundary curve for the surface? Is it the parameterization in my edit.

Comment: The boundary curve is the circle $x^2+y^2=4$, $z=0$. You restrict your parametrization to $\phi=\pi/2$, $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$. My suggestion, however, was to fill this circle in and integrate over the region it bounds in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: So it would be that $\mathbf{r}=\langle 2\cos\phi, 2\sin\phi\rangle$ and then evaluate $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))$ and $\mathbf{r}'$ and just do the integral $\oint_S \mathbf{F} \bullet d\mathbf{r}$.

Comment: No, use $\theta$ here, not $\phi$. And I'm still recommending you avoid the line integral altogether.

Comment: Okey right. I'm still not sure what the integral would look like you suggest I should use. The one in $S$ with the normal and all that?

Comment: No, integrate over the inside of the circle in the $xy$-plane. Its normal is $\mathbf k$, so $\text{curl}\,\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf k = $ and so on ...

Comment: I did the integral. Does it seem correct?

Comment: No, you need the FULL circle, $0\le\phi\le 2\pi$.

Comment: Okey thanks! Why full circle though if the original surface was half a sphere. If you move that to $xy$-plane, shouldn't we still be on the first and second quadrant of the circle.

Comment: The base of the hemisphere is the entire circle in the $xy$-plane. Draw pictures!

Comment: OF COURSE! Got it 100% now!

Comment: That last comment really made me "get it". The projection to $xy$-plane is naturally a full circle and the normal must be straight the $z$-axis so $\mathbf{k}$. Thanks @Ted Shifrin